# ERROR ITMS-90092: “This bundle is invalid..."

Tags: xcode, io, armv7, submission

When I try to submit my Xcode I receive this error:

ERROR ITMS-90092: “This bundle is invalid. Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture.”

How can I get rid of this error???
Under my valid architectures I have armv7 listed... Please Help!! And thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to bypass this error and successfully submit my app. Here is what you have to do if you already have armv7 included under build settings > valid architectures:

1. Run the app on your phone with the usb cord pugged into the computer.
2. Once the app has successfully played on your phone, unplug your phone.
3. Now go to product > archive > validate
4. Once you have done this, click submit to app store and your app should submit just fine.

Hope this helps people that encounter the same issue!